# How to make a jar file without recording the directory name?

Tags: java, jar

The folder Test contains various files and folders. I want to create a jar that contains only the Test's sub-folders and files, without the directory's name (Test) in hierarchy.

I've tried:

```
 ProcessBuilder createJarProcess2 = new ProcessBuilder("jar", "cMf", "test.jar","test");
 p = createJarProcess2.start();
 stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
 // read any errors from the attempted command
 while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(s);
 }
 p.waitFor();
 System.out.println("create jar 2  " + p.exitValue());
```

But includes also the directory's name.

Thanks

Comment: Jar is a programm, written in Java - isn't it? So it should be possible to create a Jar in pure Java, without invoking ProcessBuilder.

Comment: @user unknown: Actually 'Jar' is more accurately a renamed Zip.  It is more specialized in having particular compressions and specifying the format of the manifest file, but a Jar does not need to contain classes (or a manifest) to be a valid Jar. +1 for your 2nd point.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't dispute that, but my concern is, that you can access java.util.jar.JarFile and JarEntry natively from Java, without using a Processbuilder. That is independently from what is the content of the jarfile. It might be classes with a manifest. It might be not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[See the `-C` option](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html):

> > Temporarily changes directories to dir while processing the following inputfiles argument. Multiple -C dir inputfiles sets are allowed.

Example:

```
jar cMf test.jar -C Test .
```

Happy coding.